# Javascript animations in HTML webpage do not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to toggle an animation in CSS using a JavaScript file. However, the animation does not work. Can someone help me with it?
This is the JavaScript file. Note: The animation only works on a tablet or mobile aspect ratio. Meaning if you shrink the screen horizontally the webpage should change.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu')
const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu')

menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
  menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
  menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* Estilo de la barra de navegacion */

.navbar {
  background-color: #202020;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}


/* Estilo de el contenedor de texto de la barra de navegacion */

.navbar__container {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0px;
}


/* Estilo del logo dentro de la barra de navegacion */

#navbar__logo {
  background-color: yellow;
  background-image: yellow;
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.fa-gem {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}


/* Estilo del listado del texto dentro del navbar*/

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Acomodar los items dentro del navbar */

.navbar__item {
  height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Acomodar el boton dentro del navbar */

.navbar__btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Estilo del boton dentro del navbar */

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #E3ED02;
  color: #000;
}


/* Animaciones de cambio de color en los botones del navbar */

.button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 247);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: #8c8d74;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


/* Cambio de pantalla a tablet */

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar__menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 50vh;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .navbar__menu.active {
    background: #131313;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 50vh;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
  #navbar__logo {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .navbar__item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar__links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }
  #mobile-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translate(5%, 20%);
  }
  .navbar__btn {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  .button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Pagina personal</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar__container">
      <a href="/" id="navbar__logo">EB</a>
      <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar__menu">
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a href="/" class="navbar__links">
                            Home
                        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a href="/tech.html" class="navbar__links">
                            Tech
                        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a href="/" class="navbar__links">
                            Products
                        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__btn">
          <a href="/" class="button">
                            Sign Up
                        </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script scr="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I was expecting a menu that shows when you click a button. The button transitions into a cross when clicked, and it should show a menu that says Home, Tech, Products, and Sign up.

Comment: I don't see any code for animations in your question. I see 3 transforms (not the same thing) - do they work? Also, there is no JavaScript animations here either. These are CSS. Please edit your question and include the relevant HTML.

Comment: Ok, I included all 3 files

Comment: Closing for reason typo: should be `.navbar__menu.active {` not `.navbar__menu .active {` - since when you separate with a space that's a child, not the same element.

Comment: It for some reason works in stack overflow but not in my browser